# What font was used for the "EARNED" and "PASSED" arrows on Press Your Luck?

Tags: font-identification

On the 80s game show Press Your Luck, each player has arrows tracking their spins. The arrows read EARNED and PASSED. I've attempted to identify this font with fontsquirrel, Find My Font, and other tools but the online images are too blurry (and letters too small) so the identification tools keep seeing fuzzy letters and thus returning wrong results.

Below is the clearest image I could find on Google, with two examples of EARNED and PASSED.

[image]

Comment: Gotham XNarrow Medium is close but is not the font in the picture. I can't really tell if the text is rounded or not. I kind of think it is.

Comment: In the E, it looks like the middle horizontal line is shorter than the top and bottom lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding a classic sans serif condensed font with just seven characters from a not well defined picture is not an easy job.

I press my luck: the most similar *Seven Characters* all together are :

**Interstate Regular Condensed** (doubting about the SS)

[image: Interstate]

Comment: Interstate isn’t far off, but the R is different. The leg starts further out on the bowl in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I misread the question and thought it was for the logo so I'm leaving this here as a posterity answer for future searches.

The font has no readily available alternative but [Elephantmen Greatest Bold](https://www.fonts.com/font/comicraft/elephantmen-greatest/bold) is a near match with a little bit of rounding to its elements.

[image]

[image]

[image]